# Set values of NSMutableDictionary to values in another

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, setvalue

I did post request for retrieving data from the server. Now, I have NSDictionary with certain data. I need to display it in a chart, so I have to convert data to appropriate. Here's data which I get from the server:

```
dates =     (
        "01.01.2016",
        "01.01.2016",
        "01.01.2016"
        ...) 

closes =     {
        0 =         (
            1,
            1,
            1,
            ...)
        }
```

I need to transform it to this format:

```
{
    "01.01.2016" = 1;
    "01.01.2016" = 1;
    "01.01.2016" = 1;
    ...
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is your real name Steve Jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *dates  = ...
NSArray *closes = ...

NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary new];
for (int i = 0; i < dates.count; i++) {
    result[dates[i]] = closes[i];
}
NSLog(@"%@", result)
```

Note that dates and closes arrays must have same length

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of 'dates' and `closes` elements are equal:

```
NSMutableDictionary dataOut = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (int index = 0; index < dataIn[@"dates"].count; index++)
{
    dataOut[dataIn[@"dates"][index]] = dataIn[@"closes"][index];
}
```

Depending on how certain you are and on how fool proof you need this code to be, you may want to add checks (and error handling) to cover the above assumption.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to 2 array and you need to create dictionary then 
_productArray2 & _productArray1

```
 NSDictionary * productDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSUInteger index =0; index < _productArray1.count; index ++) {
        [productDictionary setValue:_productArray1[index] forKey:_productArray2[index]];
    }
```

and if you already have a dictionary want to replace of set value to it

```
NSArray * allKeys = [productDictionary allKeys];

for (NSUInteger index =0; index < allKeys.count; index ++) {
    [productDictionary setValue:_productArray[index] forKey:allKeys [index]];
}
```